# Setting up stripe firebase cloud function

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What am I trying to do?
I want to use Apple pay with stripe firebase-cloud function to charge the users, while reading the stripe documentation but I noticed that you need to "Prepare your API" https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard

What is my question?
In stripe documents it's mentioned that I need to " Prepare my API" (https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard) , so if I'm using the firebase stripe cloud function am I still supposed to do this step? If yes how?

Thank you

Comment: From what I have (rapidly) read from the documentation you pointed out, you could make an HTTPS Callable function based on the example they provide for node.js.

You would call this HTTP Function from your iOS, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function

Comment: It's basically saying that. When a user signs up to your application, At the same time create a stripe customer that is associated to the user signing up. (Read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions)